# Check CSV row values if they match with variable

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to check a CSV if it has a **value that matches a variable**. If it does contain that variable I want to print out *'variable present'*

I tried to check each row for matching text of the variable and each field in the row. I do not get an error message but the result is always negative.

```
import csv

old_name = "random name already present in the table"

with open("data.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ["name", "price"]
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for row in csv_reader:
        for field in row:
            if field == old_name:
                print("already there")
            else:
                print("not there")
```

Output is just 'not there' for each item in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Each row returned by iterating [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) gives you a dict containing the column name as key, you should do something like:

```
for row in csv_reader:
  if row['name'] == old_name
```